# What instead of CONVERT(TIME, x) Datepart?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have complicated query over very big table.

Long story short, when I use convert time to select period of day (let's say 12-13h, converting it from datetime row) query takes few minutes, instead of few seconds without convert!

So, I tried **datepart**, and it works well, almost instant, but, problem is, how to point to hours and minutes in same time?

Any other fast solution is more than welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use 2 date part calls in the query?

Comment: I cant, if I set datepart hour between 12 and 15 and datepart minute between 10 and 40, I will not get time between 12.10 and 15.40 that I want

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment.   It appears you want to use datepart in the where clause, I thought you wanted a column to show date part information.   See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use datePart if you are willing to do a bit of math, as shown below:

- 12:10 = 12 * 60 + 10 = 730 minutes
- 15:40 = 15 * 60 + 40 = 940 minutes

  **select *  .....
  where datepart(mi, datefield) between (12*60+10) and (15*60+40)**

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile I came up with this:

```
DATEPART(HOUR, datetimecolumn)*100 + DATEPART(MINUTE, datetimecolumn)) between 1210 and 1540
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a constant periods - i.e. - always hourly and no any floating periods - you may introduce something like "ordinal number of period" calculated field, index on it and query of it with **precalculated** period value

OR

is there are no any constant periods - try to calculate proper begin and end values prior to SELECT statement and use them in the query.

Keep in mind that using functions in where clause of query - sometimes is a bad idea. Using functions in ORDER BY clause - always bad

Answer (score 0):

You can get GETTIME from following Function

```
alter function GetTimeOnly(@_DateTime DateTime)
returns datetime
as
    begin
    return dateadd(day, -datediff(day, 0, @_datetime), @_datetime)
    end
go
```

OR YOU CAN HAVE THE TIME FROM CONVERT FUNCTION.

```
SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108) AS HourMinuteSecond,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),101) AS DateOnly
```